# Arabic cognates of Hebrew term? 2 Kings 17:13

Tags: hebrew

While studying what is means to be a seer according to [2 Kings 17:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%2017%3A13&version=ESV), one of the lexicons, called Brown-Driver-Briggs, when tracing [the root word](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2372.htm), gives a couple of what seem to be Arabic cognates, then claims to translate them, but I want to confirm the meaning.

The two words are:

[image]

[image]

The lexicon appears to indicate the words relate to being an astronomer or astrologer, but I would like to confirm that meaning.

If that is the case, in what way would being a seer in the Old Testament relate to being an astronomer or astrologer according to the Arabic language?

Comment: BDB lexicon often does this because Arabic and Hebrew are close relatives.

Comment: @Dottard. Correct. Thanks. I just want to be sure of the meaning of the Arabic terms they give.

Comment: That is odd because, while BDB often quotes an Arabic cognate, my copy of BDB does not list any for חֹזֶה either in my printed version nor the on-line version at https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2374.htm   Can you provide a source for this Arabic reference?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you could try https://judaism.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Dottard. Perhaps the question was a bit misleading, I am looking at the root chazzah:

https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2372.htm

I fixed the question.

Comment: In Koehler-Baumgartner (1958) we can find: "The Aramic word for the Hebrew 'ra'ah'," to see. "That entered the Hebrew language early on." The Arabic word cited is the same as your second word and is translated "astrologer" ... Out of my comfort zone.

Answer (score 2):

The verbal root ḥ-z-y means “to see” in Hebrew and Aramaic. The same root exists in Arabic, but only in the active participle ḥāzin in the specialised meaning “seer”, that is: “one who can see into the future”. It is commonplace that the same root has slightly different meanings in different Semitic languages.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, fdb.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here is the entry from, "Complete Word Study Dictionary Old Testament" by W Baker & E Carpenter.

> **2372. חָזָה** A verb meaning to see, to perceive.  This term is more poetic than the common ra'ah (7200).  It refers to see God (Ex 24:11;
> Job 19:26; 27, Ps 11:7; 17:15); astrological observations (Isa
> 47:13);prophetic vision and insight (Isa 1:1; Lam 2:14; Ezek 12:27;
> Hab 1:1; Zech 10:2).

Thus, the Hebrew meaning includes astrological observation as suggested in Isa 47:13.  However, these were false "seers".  For a true "seer", one of the prophets of God, I could find no reference to astrology as part of their job description.

Comment: Hi, Dottard. Thanks for this. I am, however, looking for a way to translate the two Arabic terms, which BDB claims are cognates. I would normally trust BDB, but in this case, I want to make absolutely certain they are giving the correct translation of both حَزَى ( ḥazā ) and  حَازٍ ( ḥāzin ).